# Using OpenOffice.org, is there a way to print not only the content, but also the comments for a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, openoffice, documents

I received a Word document with comments attached. The material added inline appears in a print preview, but none of the annotated comments do. Is there a way to print everything?

Comment: Might not show up in print preview, but it should print out on the page or PDF.

Comment: They don't print out on the page. I printed a sample page. I did not try exporting to PDF then printing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is.

Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice Writer -> Print Tab

Under the "Notes" section, change "None" to whatever comments you wish to print, such as "end of page".

Comment: I did that and they still don't show up in the print preview.

Comment: Perhaps it matters that the comments point at various sections in the document? I'm not entirely sure, but they reside in a bar to the right of the page, with arrows that point at the text. I suppose I could copy the text of the note out, but that seems like a waste of effort.

Comment: That's very weird, that works for me. If all else fails you can try Word viewer 2003: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=95E24C87-8732-48D5-8689-AB826E7B8FDF&displaylang=en

Comment: I tried printing a page - no notes were printed.

Comment: Using the Word viewer worked. I am still interested in getting OpenOffice.org to print these notes, however, at least for future reference.

Comment: It works for me in OpenOffice.org 3.2.0, but it did not work immediately the first time - I had to keep fooling with the settings (not sure what suddenly made it work, I was playing with a bunch of things on that Options|Writer|Print screen).  Notes do not show up in the Print Preview, but do show up when printed.